# Conversion of Unicode

Tags: python

I am a newbie in python.

I have a unicode in Tamil.

When I use the sys.getdefaultencoding() I get the output as "Cp1252"

My requirement is that when I use text = testString.decode("utf-8") I get the error "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-8: character maps to undefined"

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Is your Tamil string a Unicode string, like `u'தமிழ்'` literal, or a 8-bit string? 'Decode' means 'turn from 8-bit encoding into Unicode'; `testString.decode("utf-8")` supposes that `testString` is in utf-8. Is it so? If `ord(testString[0])` is below 256, it's 8-bit, and if it's slightly above 2900, it's likely Unicode Tamil. CP1252 is definitely a wrong code page to use, it's a European code page. Check your locale settings.

Answer (score 3):

> When I use the
>   sys.getdefaultencoding() I get the
>   output as "Cp1252"

Two comments on that: (1) it's "cp1252", not "Cp1252". Don't type from memory. (2) Whoever caused sys.getdefaultencoding() to produce "cp1252" should be told politely that that's not a very good idea.

As for the rest, let me guess. You have a `unicode` object that contains some text in the Tamil language. You try, erroneously, to decode it. Decode means to convert from a `str` object to a `unicode` object. Unfortunately you don't have a `str` object, and even more unfortunately you get bounced by one of the very few awkish/perlish warts in Python 2: it tries to make a `str` object by encoding your `unicode` string using the system default encoding. If that's 'ascii' or 'cp1252', encoding will fail. That's why you get a Unicode*En*codeError instead of a Unicode*De*codeError.

Short answer: do `text = testString.encode("utf-8")`, if that's what you really want to do. Otherwise please explain what you want to do, and show us the result of `print repr(testString)`.

Answer (score 0):

add this as your 1st line of code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

later in your code...

text = unicode(testString,"UTF-8")

Answer (score 0):

you need to know which character-encoding is testString using. if not utf8, an error will occur when using decode('utf8').