# How to translate an unprintable string to a normal string in python?

Tags: python, character

I have a string (that originally is taken from a search result of a search engine) that contains special characters such as '\xe9' and I just want to replace those characters to normal characters so that I could print them (it's a python program).

So how do I do it? It keeps writing me this error:
" File "D:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1255.py", line 12, in encode return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table) UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 11: character maps to undefined"

By the way, when I print "sys.getdefaultencoding()" it prints : Cp1255

The error originally happens in this function call: "urllib.urlencode(THE STRING)" but it also happens when I try to write "print (firstSearch['Results'][i]['Title'])" where firstSearch is a JSON that I built from the search results of the search engine...

tnx, Itamar.

Comment: Well, which characters do you want to get? You can map every byte to some other randomly, but that's propably not what you want.

Comment: What platform? What is `sys.stdout.encoding`? Edit your question to show the full traceback and full error message.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conversion of Unicode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701569/conversion-of-unicode)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are on a Windows machine, in a Hebrew locale, with the default encoding being `cp1255` which uses the hi-bit-set characters to support the Hebrew script, not Western European characters like `u'\xe9'` which is LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE.

You should be able to do

```
print u'\xe9'
```

in IDLE and observe e-acute being printed.

Note: `str(some_unicode_string)` is only of practical use (i.e. supports ALL Unicode characters) if the default encoding is `UTF-something` (usually UTF-8) or GB18030. On Windows machines, it's usually `ascii`. Yours is 'cp1255', which is not OK for arbitrary Unicode characters.

**Update** after new information provided in comments:

For your `urllib.urlencode()` problem: That function expects a `str` object. You are supplying a `unicode` object. Python 2.x attempts to encode using the system default encoding (`cp1255` in your case). `cp1255` doesn't handle `u'\xe9'`, hence the error message. You need to ascertain what encoding is expected by the website with which you are communicating. With luck, it's `UTF-8`. Instead of passing `the_unicode_string`, pass `the_unicode_string.encode(website_expected_encoding)`. If the expected encoding is `cp1255` or some other encoding that doesn't support all the unicode characters that are returned by your queries (on a different site? same site???) then you are seriously out of luck and/or you need to examine carefully how you got those `unicode` strings in the first place. See [this answer by @bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996974/python-urllib-urlencode-problem-with-oa/3997031#3997031) ... ignore the accepted answer which is much less informative.

Comment: Yeah, I'm on windows and the default encoding is Cp1255. So how do I translate the string to a regular string? My intention is not actually to print the string, but to use the string so if I can't print it, the error will occur in other lines of the code. Moreover, the original error occurred when this function is called: urllib.urlencode(THE STRING), so I need to somehow turn THE STRING to a normal encoded string so that this function call will pass.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [codecs](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#module-codecs) module to transform a given string into an encoding that you can further use (e.g. print, or pass to another function). The safest encoding for arbitrary purposes is of course ASCII, but it's also the one with the most loss.

E.g.

```
s = "\xe9 and other stuff"
s1 = codecs.encode(codecs.decode(s,'<source-encoding>', 'replace'), 'utf-8')
```

This will decode your source string into a unicode string from the encoding is it in (You need to check which encoding the search engine returns). The `replace` argument allows to replace unknown characters with '?' (which is loss of information), but there are other options as well, check the docs.

The result is then encoded into the target encoding, here for example utf-8, which is ok if e.g. you want to print the string on a terminal that supports this encoding. If you want to further process the result string, I would recommend to stick with Unicode as long as possible.

Two things to note here:

- You need to know what your input string's encoding is.
- You need to know what encoding the target function can handle. This might be different for 'print' (ascii?) and 'urllib.urlencode' (unicode?).

NB: The .encode and .decode functions are also available as string methods, so you can write `s.decode(...)` etc.

Comment: -1 because (1) Mentioning codecs.encode and codecs.decode at all constitutes obfuscation (2) mentioning "string methods" in general without saying "stick to str.decode and unicode.encode; avoid unicode.decode and str.encode (which vanish in Python 3) unless you know exactly you are doing" is unhelpful (3) 'unicode` is NOT an encoding (4) urllib.urlencode (whose name could have been better chosen) expects `str` objects and returns a `str` object; what encoding was used to produce the input is irrelevant to that function but of course needs to be known by the client and the server.

Comment: @John I find your comment rather destructive. I cannot think why mentioning a relevant Python module should be "obfuscating" (1). I also think you cannot put all best practices in an answer otherwise we would be writing books (although that would have made a good comment), but expect OPs to study further and make up their own minds (2). You also cannot be 100% precise in an answer and I use the term 'unicode' to both refer to a Python data type and its encoding (e.g. UCS-2) (3). And urllib.urlencode is obviously not able to handle arbitrary strings, hence this question in the first place (4).

Comment: (1) it's obfuscation because 0.0001% of people use its encode/decode functions, the rest of the world uses str/unicode methods. You should have mentioned codecs functions last, if at all. (2) If OPs "studied further", they wouldn't be here asking questions. (3) "unicode" is not "UCS-2" and is not an encoding; that is not "imprecise", it is WRONG. (4) You have missed the point again: urllib.urlencode can handle arbitrary `str` objects. *You* suggested ("unicode?") that it could handle `unicode` objects. Are you conflating "str" and "string"?